# SilverStripe 4 beta3 TreeDropdownField gives error: SourceObject must be a DataObject subclass

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I must be missing something simple...I'm using the documentation here: http://api.silverstripe.org/en/master/class-SilverStripe.Forms.TreeDropdownField.html and I think I'm doing this correctly, but getting the error : SourceObject must be a DataObject subclass

This is my code

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TreeDropdownField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextareaField;
class HomePage extends Page {
    private static $db = array(
        'CTA'       => 'Varchar(255)',
        'LinkText'  => 'Varchar(50)'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'PageLink'  => 'SiteTree'

    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextareaField::create('CTA', 'Call To Action Text'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TreeDropdownField::create('PageLinkID', 'What page does this call-to-action link to?', 'SiteTree'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('PageLinkText', 'Call To Action Link Text (Example: "Learn more")'), 'Content');
        $fields->removeByName('Content');
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a fully qualified class name:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab(
    'Root.Main',
    TreeDropdownField::create(
        'PageLinkID',
        'What page does this call-to-action link to?',
        SiteTree::class
    ),
    'Content'
);
```

This also goes for your model relations:

```
private static $has_one = array(
    'PageLink'  => SiteTree::class,

);
```

Comment: Hey Robbie, thank you for your reply. I tried exactly that 'SiteTree::class' and the error went away. However, now when I go into the CMS to choose a page from the dropdown and save it, it doesn't _visually_ appear to be saved, but looking in the table in the database I see "PageLinkID 2" 2 being the ID of the page I selected. So it did save. Also...now when I preview the Home Page on the front end, I now get this error: "[Emergency] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: has_one relation HomePage.PageLink references class SiteTree which doesn't exist"

So it seems I now have two problems.

Comment: Oh geez! The front end error was a typo of the template variable. My bad! Any idea on the page not showing up in the CMS as being selected? Or is this another question for another thread? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @C.Brown try updating to the latest version of CMS, framework and silverstripe-admin (the `4` branch). There was a bug recently relating to this which has been fixed.